# Pass Intent from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to transfer Intent to another activity in Xamarin.Android. Basically I need Intent.Data and Intent.ClipData to another activity, so I am using the below code to transfer the Intent but I don't know the proper way to retrieve that.

Here's the code in Main Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
intent.PutExtra("FilesURI", 0);
intent.PutExtras(intent);
StartActivity(intent);
```

In SecondActivity

```
if (intent.HasExtra("FilesURI"))
{
    var data = (Intent)intent.Extras;
    ProcessIntent(intent);
}
```

How do I retrieve Intent in second activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution, thanks to @YodaScholtz for the hint.

I wrote the following code

In MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondActivity));
intent.PutExtra("ClipData", intent.ClipData);
StartActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity code

```
if (intent.HasExtra("ClipData"))
{
  var _data = intent.Extras;
  var _clipdata = (ClipData)_data?.GetParcelable("ClipData");
  intent.ClipData = _clipdata;
  ProcessIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line: `intent.PutExtras(intent);` will copy all extra data of intent.
Assume intent has: "DATA" and "CLIPDATA" keys. You can retrieve like this in your SecondActivity

```
string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("DATA") ?? "Data not available";
```

Comment: Do you think `text` variable contains `Intent` ? I want to retrieve Intent not string

Comment: @Amit when you call `Intent.GetStringExtra()` method it returns a string if found in the Intent extras. If you're looking for an integer I'd imagine it would be `Intent.GetIntExtra()` or similar. The Intent does not need to be retrieved, but is rather passed into and present in every activity.

Comment: @YodaScholtz. Intent.ClipData contains a list of Uri's which I have to pass to another activity, is there any alternate way to achieve this. When I pass Intent and at the seco d activity I see list of Uri's in Intent.Extras (using Intellisense) that returns Bundle, but couldn't find the way to extract that.

Comment: @Amit I'd say instead of passing the intent, you should pass the ClipData as a Bundle. An Array or List is parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin documentation has a page that gives an example of doing exactly what you're asking, passing data from one activity to another via intent extras.

In summary you'll need to call the following method in the receiving activity:

```
string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("FilesURI") ?? "Data not available";
```

A more detailed example can be found in the Xamarin documentation, where the above sample was extracted from: [Passing Data Between Activities](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/)

Answer (score 0):

from one activity to others activity

Intent intent = new intent(Mainactivity.this,anotheractivityname.class);
startactivity(intent)